# Is there any way to pull active nav class into title tag in Angular

Tags: angular, nav, page-title

I have a one page Angular application. I'd like to dynamically pull text associated with the active nav class into the title tag. Thoughts?

Comment: Google ? `document.title = 'My new title'`. Just find the value of the active nav class.

Comment: @user7814645 you need to check css selectors for active elements and for non active ones. Based this information you'll be able add more details to your question and get correct answer as angular code.